# Android - Adding Views on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

I have a login activity which has recover login and register features. If you hit either the recover button or register button, it adds a new view to the layout depending on which you pressed. I have a onRetainNonConfigurationInstance that saves if either is up, and in my onCreate I check for that string, but I seem to be unable to add the view to the layout in onCreate or onPostCreate of the Activity. How can I add the dynamically built view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use `ViewGroup.addView(View v)` to add a view to a `ViewGroup` (a layout is a ViewGroup).

So if you have in your xml file, say, `LinearLayout` with some id, say, `R.id.root` then in `onCreate()` you can first find that layout using `LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById()` then call `root.addView(yourSavedView)`.

You can first try to add some view you have inflated before from an XML by means of `View.inflate()`. This way you will know the adding to layout itself works (or not). Then you can try to add your saved view to make sure it was saved correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your question wrong. Sorry for my English.
But if i understand it right try to set configChanges for your activity in manifest file.

```
<activity android:name="yourActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:configChanges="orientation"/>
```